# Синтаксис JSS в ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, style, create-react-app

Как задать диву два класса в ReactJS?
В html выглядит так:

```
<div class="class_1 class_2"></div>
```

Как застилизовать через JSS (про JSS в рунете совсем нет инфы)?
В css выглядит так:

```
.class_1.class_2{
  color: black;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

Comment: `<Component className="class_1 class_2"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать два класса - конкатенировать строки самостоятельно или установить `classnames` и использовать его.
Самостоятельно:

```
const classname1 = 'foo';
const classname2 = 'bar';

<div class=`${classname1} ${classname2}`></div>
```

Про `classnames` можно прочитать [здесь](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames).